# How to modify animations with @media

Tags: html, css

I have an animation, https://adsler.co.uk/contact-us/, which displays correctly in mobile but incorrectly in desktop. It's too wide in desktop (should've same width as contact form) and this css won't rectify.

```
@media (max-width: 5000px) and (min-width: 768px) 
{.contact::before.contact::after {content: attr(data-text);
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 50%;
height: 100%; 
}}
```

Why not? Despite multiple divs under one query, my css checker doesn't challenge it so in theory it should work.

If I alter `width: 100%;` to `width: 50%` in the set cascade, it does work, but that of course means the whole thing being altered which would make `width: 50%` too small for mobile.

The html is:

```
<div class="contact" data
text="CONTACT">CONTACT</div>
```

CSS FOR ANIMATION

```
page-id-1239 { background: #000; display: flex;
align- 
items: center;
height: 100vh;
justify-content: center; }
.contact {
font-family: arial;
position: relative;
color: #fff;

text-align: center;
font-size: 7rem;
max-width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.contact::before
.contact::after {
content: attr(data-text);
position: 
absolute; top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%; height: 100%;
}

.contact::before {
left: 2px;
clip: rect(79px, 1200px, 86px, 0);
text-shadow: -1px 0 red;
background: #000;
animation: brasil-anim-2 1s infinite linear alternate- 
reverse;
}

.contact:after {
left: -2px;
clip: rect(79px, 1200px, 86px, 0);
text-shadow: -1px 0 blue
000; animation: brasil-anim-1 1s infinite linear alternate- 
reverse;
Animation-delay: -1s;
}
@keyframes brasil-anim-1 {
0% {
Clip: rect(20px, 1200px, 76px, 0);
}
20% {
Clip: rect(19px, 1200px, 16px, 0);
}
40% {
Clip: rect(16px, 1200px, 3px, 0);
}
60% {
Clip: rect(62px, 1200px, 78px, 0);
}
80% {
Clip: rect(25px, 1200px, 13px, 0);
}
100% {
Clip: rect(53px, 1200px, 86px, 0);
}
}
@keyframes brasil-anim-2 {
0% {
Clip: rect(79px, 1200px, 86px, 0);
}

20% {
Clip: rect(20px, 1200px, 30px, 0)
}
40% {
Clip: rect(25px, 1200px, 5px, 0)
}
60% {
Clip: rect(65px, 1200px, 85px}

80% {
Clip: rect(120px, 1200px, 145px, 0)
}
100% {
clip: rect(95px, 1200px, 75px, 0)
}}
```

Comment: Can I see your whole HTML please?

Comment: You need to separate multiple selectors with a comma.

Comment: @BugsYes sir. Thanks. Gave you an upvote for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.contact::before.contact::after` is an invalid selector, if you want to address both ::before and ::after you need to write it like so: 
To explain further: The original selector is not invalid per se, it just doesn't evaluate to any element that can exist. It would mean to select an after element with the class 'contact' that is ::before an element of contact. And since before and after can't have classes the mentioned selector can never resolve to anything on any webpage. To select two separate elements you need to separate them with `,`:

```
.contact::before, .contact::after {
  /*here is your css*/
 }
```

Comment: That worked. How do you know this stuff? Brilliant. Marked you correct and upvoted. Thanks for your time.